# Don't have the hiring manager's contact info. Should I send a thank you email via LinkedIn?

Tags: interviewing

I learned from the recruiter that the hiring manager is the CMO, who I presented to (along with two would-be peer and a Director) a couple days ago.

But I don't have the hiring manager's info. Should I send a LinkedIn message thanking, or just to the recruiter asking her to pass it on?

Also, how soon should I send it? The interview was Friday.

Comment: Why do you feel you need to?

Comment: I understand it's good practice to thank the hiring manager. A trusted friend said thank you emails are overrated. So I'm at a loss.

Comment: Yes, you thank them during the meeting. You don't seek them out over LinkedIn. There may be a cultural thing at play, and I may be wrong, so you might want to throw a location in your tags.

Comment: Okay, great. This is the first interview I go through so it's probably just that. I won't reach out to the hiring manager. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think I've ever received a thank you from a candidate except in response to an email that I sent them - and I've never expected one...

Comment: Shouldn't it be the manager that thanks you?

Comment: It might make a difference if you have a meaningful followup besides just “thank you.” If that’s all you have to say, I wouldn’t bother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't thank the managers directly unless you get another interview or get hired.  If I or another manager had thank you from all the people we interviewed I might just delete my LinkedIn account.  The sentiment is nice, but either thank at the end of the interview or after hired.

Honestly mutual appreciation is implied to me as you want a job and they want a good employee.  Keep the appreciative attitude, but don't seat the missed thanks.

I was on your side before and felt similarly, but after being on the other side, it's not that big of a deal to thank or miss the thanks.  If your in the interview good idea, but after you leave wait on them and deal with the recruiter.

Comment: Does this advice apply to the recruiter as well? It sounds like I should hold off on all communication until I hear from them.

Comment: Recruiter is fine, they are there to help you get a job, just be aware of being "annoying" vs genuine human interaction.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy to deduce someone's work email address. If you have the recruiter's email, you could work out the pattern to email the CMO directly.

As opposed to the other two answers, I see the thank you note as a very valuable tool for a few reasons:

1) Showing appreciation is a good thing (however, LinkedIn is not always the right method of communication)

2) It reminds the interviewer about you and gets them thinking about you as a candidate

3) You can use that thank you letter to remind them why you're the right candidate. Thank them for the interesting conversation about "X" and how your experience with "Y" can directly help solve the problem they have with "X".

Another option, if you can't track down the email, albeit slower, is to send a thank you note to the office addressed to the CMO.

Best of luck,
— Ask Tigress

Answer (score 1):

The good time to thank is the end of the interview. This is the time to show your attitude towards the interview.

Any contact later, except for another round of interviews or replying to accept/reject the contract is considered overreaction and may raise a red flag - it may seem you are stalking on them.

In the excptions above, you can thank for being promoted to the next step or for them informing you about the result. And again; the thank, if you want to thank, should be part of the immediate response from you.

As mutt already stated, if the hiring manager was to get thank-you from all people interviewed, they will block any LinkdeIn traffic and blacklist all the interviewees.